# Can not start Squid's service

Tags: server

When I try to run `systemctl start squid.service`, I get the following error message:

```
 Job for squid.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status squid.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

`journalctl` returned this information regarding the Squid service:

```
Mar 30 06:02:25 localhost systemd: Starting Squid caching proxy...
Mar 30 06:02:25 localhost squid: squid: ERROR: Could not read pid file
Mar 30 06:02:25 localhost squid: /var/run/squid.pid: (13) Permission denied
Mar 30 06:02:25 localhost systemd: squid.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 30 06:02:25 localhost systemd: Failed to start Squid caching proxy.
Mar 30 06:02:25 localhost systemd: Unit squid.service entered failed state.
Mar 30 06:02:25 localhost systemd: squid.service failed.
Mar 30 06:03:01 localhost systemd: Started Session 175 of user root.
Mar 30 06:03:01 localhost systemd: Starting Session 175 of user root.
```

How can I run Squid on my system?

Comment: Are you starting the service as superuser? If not, do `sudo systemctl start squid.service`

Comment: This didn,t help me.

Comment: Does the pid file already exist: `/var/run/squid.pid`. If yes delete it and try again

Answer (score 2):

There's a pre-existing PID file that is causing Squid to get annoyed. Put simply, run the following command to delete the PID file:

```
sudo rm /var/run/squid.pid
```

Then, kill any current running versions of Squid by running the below command or just rebooting your computer:

```
sudo killall -9 squid
```

Finally, start the Squid service as normal. It should fire right up.

Comment: `rm: cannot remove '/var/run/squid.pid': No such file or directory`;;;;`squid: no process found`. But it's there: `squid.service - Squid Web Proxy Server - Loaded: loaded - Active: inactive (dead)`